# Acquisition graph is not showing updated data in Windows Dev Center for windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-dev-center

In Windows Dev center App Overview area, Today is 7th Dec 2015 but in acquisitions graph its is showing data till 02 dec 2015.
I am not understand why it is not reflecting till 07 dec 2015.
I have checked with third party tool dashboard that 10 people installed the app on 07 dec 2015.
Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Same for me too .. I see only outdated acquisition data form 02 Dec.

This has happened in the past, so be patient and wait for the problem to be fixed, or contact directly MS support and ask them about the problem.